# Simple-peer, how the candidate data is transferred?

Tags: webrtc, simple-peer

I am using Simple-peer to build a webrtc application. To establish connection, we need to first send the offer and receive the answer. After that onicecandidate event gets triggered generating the candidate, we are required to send the candidate data to remote peer. The remote peer will than run addicecandidate and send back the remote candidate data which need to be added on localpeer using addicecandidate and connection gets established.

I want to understand how simple-peer is handling transfer of candidate data. The SDP data related to OFFER and ANSWER is required to be transferred using server in between, in one of the example socket-io has been used. But how the candidate data is getting transferred?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

In simple-peer the signal from `peer.on('signal', data=>{})` contains all the webrtc signaling data. If you print out the value of the signal you'll see it contains sdp, offer and answer all labeled to identify which is which.